# "My compliments to..."

Tags: phrases, vocabulary

Wonder if anyone knows the provenance of the phrase "my compliments to" and why it entered use (and dropped out of use)? I don't mean "my compliments to the chef" or variants thereof but phrases like "my compliments to Mr. So-and-So and I will see him at six" etc.

Comment: How is complimenting the chef linguistically different from complimenting Mr So-and-So?

Comment: This is 'compliments' in the sense of 'formal greetings' rather than 'praise'. It's a way of making a request (or other message) sent by a third party extra polite. This was especially important when social hierarchies were strongly defined and the messenger might be a person of lower status.

Comment: "*Please convey* my complements to the chef."

Comment: "Compliments of the season" is still used at Christmas time in the sense of greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Seventeenth Century Diplomacy

In 17th c. literature, *compliments* — sometimes spelled *complements* and always plural — belongs to the language of diplomacy.  *To do/make one’s compliments* to royalty or other highly placed personages was to greet them formally, the accent on social obligation and unspoken protocol rather than any content of the greeting itself:

> Quasmez’ Embassadours …did their *complements* to Zelmatida, as to the rightfull successour of the Incaes; — Marin Le Roy, Sieur de Gomberville, William Browne, trans., *The History of Polexander*, 1647. EEBO
>
> Some doubted if the Embassadours … should be received to make their *complements* to the king without letters of credence; … — Sir William Lower, *A Relation* (of Charles II’s visit to Holland), 1660. EEBO
>
> As soon as ever we were returned to Athens, all the men made their *compliments* to Theramenes upon that occasion; and all the ladies did the like to Melicrita… — Mme. de Scudery, Ferrand Spence, trans., *Conversations upon Several Subjects*, 1683. EEBO
>
> All the corporations of Mayence went forth to meet the prince, and made their *compliments* to him in Latin: and the duke, who understood other things as well as the taking of towns, and winning of Battels, answerd all their *complements*, and all their speeches in Latin... — Pierre Coste,  trans., Nahum Tate, *The Life of Lewis of Bourbon*, 1693. EEBO
>
> Tuesday last the Duke of Marlborough receiv’d the [*Complements*](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000489/17121227/005/0003) of our Magistrates, …  —*Newcastle Courant*,  27 Dec. 1712. BNA (paywall)

By the 18th c., personal letters would often end with a phrase requesting that the addressee forward *compliments*, i.e.,  greetings, to a third party. Thus in two letters of Jonathan Swift:

> The whole family of my ladies send their [*compliments*](https://archive.org/details/oed02arch/page/730). (1733)
>
> I made his royal highness your *compliments*, which he accepted with much satisfaction. (1739)

A *compliment of condolence*, paid or made, was a formal condolence call to “pay one’s respects”:

> This Pompous Cavalcade Attended his Eminency to the Castle; who there alighting, ascended into the Room where the King's [[Jan III Sobieski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_III_Sobieski)] Body lay; Expos'd in his Royal Robes; and after he had said a short Prayer, he pass'd on to the Queen's Apartment, to pay her his [*Complements of Condolence*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ecNCAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA216&dq=%22complements+of+condolence%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJp-m6x_fdAhXMCiwKHeWQBlQQ6AEILzAC)…  —*The Present State of Europe, Or, The Historical and Political Mercury*, July 1696.

In the late 18th–early 19th c., though the formal, diplomatic sense remained, people of most any social class would make compliments of condolence:

> By this time Lady Griskin had come to make her formal [*compliments*](https://books.google.de/books?id=IPwdAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22compliments+of+condolence%22+Smollet&source=bl&ots=EjqyAOH9Qs&sig=dVcIZT54m2a7xiGSvG1tD6h1uCk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_2KWU9ffdAhVFmIsKHcIGAHIQ6AEwCXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22compliments%20of%20condolence%22%20Smollet&f=false) of condolence to Mrs. Tabitha, on this domestic calamity ; and that prudent maiden, whose passion was now cooled, thought proper to receive her ladyship so civilly, that a reconciliation immediately ensued. — Tobias Smollet, *The Expedition of Humphry Clinker*, 1771.
>
> The more distant relations of the old lady, and I among the number, came to pay our [*compliments of condolence*](https://books.google.de/books?id=nCsvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA270&dq=%22compliments+of+condolence%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil6Iu_6ffdAhVBtIsKHZ7BAzY4ChDoAQhVMAk), and to salute the deceased, after the manner of our country. — Oliver Goldsmith, “Letter XCVI,”*Works*, 1835.

#### Eighteenth, Nineteenth Century Social Communication

One 17th c. attestation of *compliments* falls out of the usual aristocratic pattern:

> I shall conclude my complements to the reader with two requests; … — Joshua Childrey, *Britannia Baconica*, 1662. EEBO

This, of course, concludes an author’s preface, in a sense, the writer’s greeting to his readers. It is written, not spoken in person, and though the cost of books and widespread illiteracy precluded the lower classes, the expression is not particularly marked for class.

*To send/present one’s compliments* emerges in [polite, formulaic speech in the 18th century](https://archive.org/details/oed02arch/page/730) as a form of greeting, especially in personal correspondence.  [Letter-writing guides](https://books.google.de/books?id=dAaAWXojc1UC&pg=PA114&dq=%22compliments%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhuKXvnPfdAhXllYsKHUI8AY0Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22compliments%20to%22&f=false) regularly included examples of *cards of compliment*, which, along with [visiting cards](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visiting_card), were a staple of social communication among the upper and middle classes in a time when servants could hand-deliver and the telephone was not even on the horizon.

To attain the proper form, Samuel Johnson’s [*New London Letter Writer*](https://books.google.de/books?id=cNgNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22New+London+letter+writer%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJwr-z8vfdAhUP36QKHf4kC1MQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=compliment&f=false) gives the following advice:

> Cards of compliments should be short, easy, and consistent with politeness. They must begin with the title and stile of the writer—and care must be taken immediately after to mention in a respectful manner, the stile or title of those to whom they are addressed ; they must contain but one subject, and that should be expressed with elegance and perspicuity.

The guide then gives several examples of the proper form:

> MISS MASSIE’S respectful compliments to Miss Barton, entreats the honor of her company this afternoon to a dish of tea.
>   _Tuesday Morn.
>
> MISS BARTON’S compliments to Miss Massie, is happy to accept her agreeable invitation.
>
> SIR AARON  HARTNELL’S compliments to Lord Bradbee, should esteem it as a favour to be obliged with his company to take an airing to Richmond—the coach to be at the door at two.
>   *11o’Clock in the Morning.*
>
> LORD BRADBEE’S respectful compliments to Sir Aaron Hartnell, will be happy to attend Sir Aaron punctually at the time.
>   *12 o’Clock in the Morning*.  — Samuel Johnson, *New London Letter-Writer*, 1790, 93f.

Such short communications were always couched in the third person, maintaining a formal register even though the examples inviting someone to take tea or go on a carriage ride with such short notice would suggest a certain intimacy. Using the third person also meant a signature was not required.

While Johnson’s guide insists the text of a card of compliment have only one subject, his examples have no *grammatical* subject unless one supplies an elided pronoun.

This formula was observed well into the next century:

[image]

> Mr. Moran presents his [*compliments*](https://archive.org/details/lettertowilliaml00mora/page/n0) to Mr. Garrison, and has the honor to include herewith a letter received for him at this Legation.
>   N. S. Legation, London, 3 July 1867.

The practice of hand-delivering cards of compliment seems not to have survived much beyond the turn of the 20th c., as one writer notes in 1911:

> [*“Cards of compliment”*](https://books.google.de/books?id=RMUuAQAAIAAJ&q=%22cards+of+compliment%22&dq=%22cards+of+compliment%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigzezcjfjdAhWD2CwKHa3YANoQ6AEILTAC) is a phrase as meaningless in these days of marconigrams, automobiles, and air ships, as is Sanskrit to an Eskimo... — *The Conductor and Brakeman* 28 (1911) 96.

At the same time, however, Christmas cards with a message familiar since the 1770s became popular:

[image]

[*Source*](https://ephemeraobscura.com/products/compliments-of-the-season-1910s-antique-postcard-butterfly-winged-fairy-edwardian-fantasy-art-card-paper-ephemera-used)

The equivalent today, of course, is “Season’s Greetings.”

#### Twenty-First Century Survival

While cards of compliment have gone the way of the whalebone corset, their phrasing is still current where this usage of *compliments* began: in the language of diplomacy. A 2014 handbook of the US Department of State outlines the proper wording for short correspondence:

> The Secretary of State presents his (her) [*compliments*](https://archive.org/details/nsia-by15p1.5v8Iq/page/n4?q=compliments) to His (Her) Excellency the Ambassador of (country) and has the honor to…”

The handbook is quite specific that the phrase *has the honor* is not to be used when addressing a charge d’affaires ad interim, presumably because the position is technically vacant and anyone below that rank apparently does not honor the Secretary of State by receiving a [note verbale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_verbale).

#### Conclusion

Beyond the State Department and other diplomatic missions writing in English, *compliments*, whether as sincere greeting or semantically vacant formula, was at home in a pre-WWI upper and middle class world of few telephones and servants who manned the front door and hand-delivered messages. While the Christmas greeting survived, it was mostly replaced by a more modern expression except in nostalgic reproductions. Compliments of condolence/congratulations/thanks also yielded to other terms.